# What visa does my family need to go with me on my business trip to Hong Kong?

Tags: tourist-visas, hong-kong, business-travel, nepali-citizens

I am a Nepalese citizen. I am visiting Hong Kong for one week for a business trip for which I will be issued an invitation letter from the company. My wife and children also want to travel with me. In this case, is it appropriate to ask the inviting company to include their names in my invitation letter or shall I apply for visit visa for them?

Answer (score 3):

Applicants for a business visa require an invitation letter, but visit visas do not. http://www.chinese-embassy.org.uk/eng/visa/rcgadq/t519931.htm Your family will be accompanying you as visitors, therefore IMHO it’s not necessary for the inviting company to include their names in the invitation letter, unless the company is covering all or part of their expenses. 
All visitors to HK who do not qualify for visa-free entry need to apply in their own right https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html